# Validating a Collection of IPv4s

Tags: ruby, validation

I have a method within a class that validates all proxy addresses are valid on initialization. I've tried to refactor this a bit, but this seems to be the best I can do. Any suggestions and/or tips as to how I can possibly improve this method?

```
def valid?(proxies)
  return false if !proxies.is_a?(Array) || proxies.empty?
  ipv4_address = /^((\d{1,3}[\.]){3}\d{1,3}:\d+)$/
  proxies.each do |proxy|
    return false if proxy !~ ipv4_address
    octets = proxy.scan(/\d+/).map(&:to_i).first(4)
    return false unless octets.all? { |octet| octet.between?(0, 255) }
  end
  true
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only simplification I can think of is using a bit more complex regex to match the IP address without having to iterate over the octets:

```
def valid?(proxies)
  return false if !proxies.is_a?(Array) || proxies.empty?
  ipv4_address = /^((25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d\d|[1-9]\d|\d)\.){3}(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d\d|[1-9]\d|\d):\d+$/
  proxies.each do |proxy|
    return false if proxy !~ ipv4_address
  end
  true
end
```

This regex is based on the one in the [`ipaddress`](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/ipaddress/0.8.0/IPAddress/IPv4) package.

Comment: Nice, I originally intended on writing one huge pattern, but instead broke into two parts. Does ruby support multiline regex?

Comment: Add an `x` at the end to have your regex ignore whitespace.

Answer (score 1):

You might decide to add a method to Array, so that you can just call `%w(4.4.4.4 8.8.8.8).ipv4?`. I originally looked to use `!detect` but `all?` is much clearer for avoiding double negation. Also note that self (e.g., `self.all?`) is unnecessary when opening a class.

```
class Array
  def ipv4?
    return false if empty?
    ipv4_address = /^((25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d\d|[1-9]\d|\d)\.){3}
                      (25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d\d|[1-9]\d|\d)$/x
    all? { |address| address =~ ipv4_address }
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Ruby has an [`IPAddr` class](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.5/libdoc/ipaddr/rdoc/IPAddr.html) in the standard library. I would use `IPAddr` objects instead of `String`s to represent IP addresses.

Trying to create an instance for an invalid IP address raises an exception, so you'll have to handle that case. Once you've done that, though, you're guaranteed to only work with valid IP addresses in the rest of you application.

```ruby
proxies = proxies.map { |ip| IPAddr.new(ip) rescue false }

def valid?(proxies)
  proxies.all?(&:ipv4?)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Some comments:

- `return false if !proxies.is_a?(Array)`: IMO you shouldn't test the type of an method arguments.
- `proxies.each`. I'd recommend using the right functional abstraction, not the generic `each`. In this case: `Enumerable#all?`

I'd write:

```
def valid?(proxies)
  !proxies.empty? && proxies.all? do |proxy|
    proxy.match(Ipv4Address) && proxy.split(".").all? { |s| s.to_i.between?(0, 255) }
  end
end
```

Comment: Awesome answer! just to be sure, I'm assuming ```Ipv4Address``` represents a custom pattern, correct? Also, why isn't it recommended to check if proxies is of proper type?

Comment: 1) Yes, it's the regular expreesion. 2) Do you check the type of every argument of every method? why here? in a dynamic language you trust the caller.